# need query for below requirement

Tags: android

I need a query which should display the exact match first and then display rest in ascending order.

for example , I have 3 elements namely

```
ms office
office
ab office
```

now my search text is `office` 
then the list should display

```
office 
ab office 
ms office
```

all the above three records available in DB .

I cant do the ascending directly as `ab office` comes first in the list .

I am writing this query for android, so direct query on android very much appreciated.

Thanks,
Gobi.S

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT office_name 
FROM your_table
ORDER BY CASE WHEN office_name = 'office' THEN 1
              WHEN office_name = 'ab office' THEN 2
              WHEN office_name = 'ms office' THEN 3
         END
```